# The u before strings

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, beautifulsoup

Using beautifulsoap I had parsed some values from an html table as follows:

```
for string in soup.stripped_strings:
    all_tds.append(string)
```

when I simply print the strings as

```
for string in soup.stripped_strings:
    print string
```

I get all the strings in the page but when I store it in a list as in 1st snippet and then print the list I get a u(unicode) in front of the string as below

```
[u'stormvirux (4pa11cs031)', u'Semester:', u'5', u'Result:\xa0\xa0FIRST CLASS', u'Subject', u'External', u'Internal', u'Total', u'Result', u'Software Engineering (10IS51)', u'58', u'24', u'82', u'P', u'Systems Software (10CS52)', u'70', u'24', u'94', u'P', u'Operating Systems (10CS53)', u'58', u'18', u'76', u'P', u'Database Management Systems (10CS54)', u'42', u'25', u'67', u'P', u'Computer Networks - I (10CS55)', u'62', u'23', u'85', u'P', u'Formal Languages & Automata Theory (10CS56)', u'37', u'24', u'61', u'P', u'Database Applications Laboratory (10CSL57)', u'40', u'25', u'65', u'P', u'Systems Software & Operating Systems Lab. (10CSL58)', u'40', u'21', u'61', u'P', u'Total Marks:', u'591']
```

If I try to write `string` directly to file `fl.write(string)` I get the error

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 7-8: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Why is this happening and what can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `codecs.open()` or `io.open()` to open a text file using an appropriate text encoding (i.e. `encoding="..."`) instead of opening a bytefile with `open()`.

Comment: in general, it won't work for a html text. `BeautifulSoup` has special support for converting an html text into bytes.

Comment: Sure, but the asker is outputting fragments from the parsed document, not the document itself.

Answer (score 2):

You see the representation of Unicode strings that are contained in the list. When you print a list, `repr()` is called on each item in it:

```
>>> s = u'text…'
>>> s
u'text\u2026'
>>> print(s)
text…
>>> print([s]) # <-- a list with a single item (the string)
[u'text\u2026']
```

`u''` is a syntax for Unicode literals that may be used to defined Unicode strings in Python source code. Note: if you use non-ascii characters inside a string literal then you should define the source code encoding at the top of the module e.g., `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`.

To fix `UnicodeEncodeError` when writing to a file, you need to convert Unicode strings to bytes. [`BeautifulSoup` provides several html-specific ways](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output) to do it.

Note: In general, the generic `codecs.open()` or `io.open()` [suggested by @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22004397/4279) won't be appropriate for an html text e.g., they don't modify `<meta charset="...">` tag.

Comment: When you print a list, I believe ``list.__str__()`` is called. [Python documentation on ``object.__str__()``](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__)

Comment: @tsroten: you believe wrong. Define a class with both methods and see for yourself.

Comment: I did. ``__str__()`` was called. If you read the link I posted, you'll see in the documentation that it says ``__repr__()`` is called if ``__str__()`` is not defined. However, list has both.

Comment: @tsroten: yes. I meant items of the list (we are interested in strings inside the list). As my answer says: *"When you print a list, repr() is called on each item in it"* not `str()` as I'd assumed your comment implied.

Comment: Okay, you are right that ``repr()`` is called on each list object. However, it is also true that ``list.__str__()`` is called when a list is printed, not ``list.__repr__()`` (if they are both defined). So, looks like we are both right.

Comment: Looks like you realized the same thing. Guess I didn't read your answer close enough. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting them to strings:

```
for string in soup.stripped_strings:
    all_tds.append(str(string))
```

Here it is with a list comprehension:

```
all_tds = [str(string) for string in soup.stripped_strings]
```

Comment: I get UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 7-8: ordinal not in range(128) but when I try str(repr(string)) it executes and but the list still contains u

Comment: do not convert Unicode text into bytestrings unless you must. BeautifulSoup works with Unicode internally as well as any program that works with text should do.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I don't think we are converting to byte strings here. Instead, we are converting unicode strings to strings.

Comment: @Stormvirux Leaving them as unicode strings is probably the better approach, as @J.F. Sebastian mentions. The only time you will see the ``'u'`` is when you print the actual list object. Does your code require you to print the list and for that list to not have the u? If so, then leave the values as unicode strings and ``print str(all_tds).replace("u'", "'")``.

Comment: See @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams's answer to fix the error when calling ``fl.write(string)``.